# WinXP Get DVD/CD Drives Working

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, dvd, optical-drive, compact-disc

I have 2 different drives that are not currently working.

It show's the traditional yellow flag, to indicate there are problems.

When I try to run updates, it says the drive isn't there.

And I can't find specific drivers for these devices.

HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-H10L SCSI CdRom Device
SONY CD-RW CRX230EE SCSI CdRom Device

Top one is an LG Lightscribe dvd rom burner, 2nd one a standard cd-rom burner by sony, both internal devices.

As I can not afford to replace them, I am hoping for some tips to resurrect them to full functionality.

Any suggestions, tips or recommendations?

Comment: CD drives don't take drivers. This may not be a windows issue. Does the BIOS show them?

Comment: Yes, and but it doesn't show up in my computer.

Comment: are you able to boot off a CD from either of them?  (just checks that they are able to operate at that stage).

Comment: maybe it's the SCSI aspect of it that is the issue 'cos any CD drives i've ever used have not needed drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, but I found this video on youtube, not mine, and it solved my problems.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3zYqchojT8

Really wierd fix, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In the Hardware tab of System Properties, click on Uninstall, one at a time for each device.
Close that out, reboot and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the specific make and model of the device, plug those into google and look for device drivers that way.

If you don't know the specific make and model of the device, look in the device properties for the PCI vendor and model numbers and plug those into google. They will be part of the device string and will look something like USB\VID_413C&PID_818D - this implies the vendor ID is 413C and the product Id is 818D. Plug those into Google (or your favourite search engine) and this should help you find the make and model number of the device. Use this information to find drivers for your system, and away you go.

Comment: have you ever heard of windows needing drivers to see a cd drive?

Comment: Yes I have - in particular CD drives attached via USB and bluray drives sometimes need drivers.

Comment: Can you give a make/model of such a CD drive?

Comment: No, but I can point you to a Google results page of me searching for "CD drivers" with 51 million results if you like.

Comment: Just for fun, here's a big page of drivers for CD devices from a wide variety of suppliers: http://www.computerhope.com/drivers/cdrom.htm

Comment: that just links to support pages. I went to some, I see firmware updates and manuals. And the page mentions the generic DOS driver.  I don't see links to windows drivers for any cd drives.

Comment: It seems like you're wilfully ignoring the fact that a quick google search will find lots of examples of Windows CD drivers, but here's one that I found in 2 seconds by Googling http://www.nodevice.com/driver/GCD-50X/get42350.html

Comment: Or this forum post, for instance http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/257-63-driver

Comment: Or this one http://forums.techarena.in/windows-x64-edition/746458.htm

Comment: Or this one http://www.techrepublic.com/forum/questions/101-226563/cddvd-rom-not-working-in-windows-xp-x64-pro. Do you need me to keep going?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2720/discussion-between-barlop-and-securitymatt)

Comment: Every single link you posted doesn't support what you said, for further info, see chat.